# Mocking react-native-async-storage on Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, asyncstorage

I am testing functions which depend on `@react-native-community/async-storage`, so obviously my tests must mock that library.

And so I do this inside of my `jestSetupFile.js`:

```
import mockAsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock';
jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage', () => mockAsyncStorage);
```

Which is direct instruction from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage/blob/master/docs/Jest-integration.md

However, the file being exported has `type` keywords, which my JavaScript environment cannot parse:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/someuser/myprojects/myproject/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock.js:6
    type KeysType = Array<string>;
         ^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Sure enough, when I inspect the `async-storage-mock.js` file at that path, it contains the `type` keywords, which I believe are the root cause of this issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution was to switch to `mock-async-storage`

My `jestSetupFile.js`:

```
import MockAsyncStorage from 'mock-async-storage';
const mockImpl = new MockAsyncStorage()
jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage', () => mockImpl);
```

^^ The above mocking code did not work when done at the beginning of my test scripts themselves, though my other mock code usually works there. This only worked when added to the `jestSetupFile.js` which I define in package.json:

```
"jest:"  {
   "setupFiles": [
      "./jestSetupFile.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys ! This is really awesome !

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, you can do that with community package [@react-native-community/async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) recommended by [React-Native official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)

Everything is explain in their [doc](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest#with-jest-setup-file)

1. In your Jest config (probably in package.json) add setup files location:

```js
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["./path/to/jestSetupFile.js"]
}
```

2. Inside your setup file, set up Async Storage mocking:

```js
import mockAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock';
    
jest.mock('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage', () => mockAsyncStorage);
```